# Accidentally deleted folder containing system volume information

Tags: permissions, 22.04, hard-drive, users, media

I am unable to see folders or files. Please see the attached image and give me a solution.
[image: Error-message-window]
[image: See in that screenshot that everything will clear]

Comment: I tried this but not working........ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda4
Refusing to operate on read-write mounted device /dev/sda4